# Alert generation on unseen data using deep learning

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I am new in neural network and deep learning, trying to create a deep learning model to classify images. While reading blogs and videos, a question comes in my mind and not able to find the correct answer on internet. So that's the main reason to post question here.

My question is **how can i generate alert on unseen data?**

**E.g.**
My trained model is able to classify following objects in the image:

- Truck
- Car
- Bike etc.

But i want to generate an alert for given **bicycle** image to trained model. The point here is to be note that intentionally i am giving bicycle image. The current model predict it as a bike because its most of the features are matching with bike along with probability values for truck and car.

Can anyone suggest me how can i implement this in deep learning?

Comment: At the best you can add another class/(+1 in the last softmax) and let it remain like that because doing so will make you know that your.model thinks it can't recognise the either of the 3

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing easy that comes to my mind here.
Adding a garbage class is not good idea as it would deteriorate the rest of the model. Two solutions come here:

1. You add a bicycle class or other classes that can be problematic in your opinion due to close features with your base classes, and train again. Complicated to be exhaustive with all situations.
2. You define a threshold of confidence of your model: for example if there is no probability more than 95% then the model is not confident in its choice and you should not trust him. Good and larged models should stay at equiprobable choices at the softmax mater when the features are not recognized well.